# How to sort this object by sortorder

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I want to do sorting in this object by its key `sortOrder` on its value. I need to use PHP.

```
Array
(
    [subtotal] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [code] => subtotal
                    [value] => 838.9000
                    [label] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
                        (
                            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Subtotal
                            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                     )
    [sortOrder] => 10
                )

        )

    [shipping] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [code] => shipping
                    [field] => shipping_amount
                    [value] => 25.0000
                    [label] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
                        (
                            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Shipping & Handling
                            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [sortOrder] => 30
                )

        )

    [weee_ord_totals] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [code] => weee_ord_totals
                    [label] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
                        (
                            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => FPT
                            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [value] => 209.58
                    [base_value] => 209.58
                    [sortOrder] => 15
                )

        )

    [sbs_excl] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [code] => sbs_excl
                    [value] => 1.0000
                    [base_value] => 1.0000
                    [label] => Single Bottle Surcharge (1)
                )

        )

    [tax] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [code] => tax
                    [block_name] => tax
                    [sortOrder] => 40
                )

        )

    [giftcards] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [code] => giftcards
                    [block_name] => giftcards
                    [area] => frontend
                )

        )

    [grand_total] => Magento\Framework\DataObject Object
        (
            [_data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [code] => grand_total
                    [field] => grand_total
                    [strong] => 1
                    [value] => 1029.2300
                    [label] => Magento\Framework\Phrase Object
                        (
                            [text:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Grand Total
                            [arguments:Magento\Framework\Phrase:private] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [sortOrder] => 100
                )

        )

)
```

I tried to sort using `ksort()`, but it's not working for me.

Comment: Provide a [mre] of the issue please including your attempt so far and the specific problem encountered ("not working" isn't a useful problem description, and "I need" isn't a meaningful question), as per the [ask] guide. Also indicate if you researched any other possible solutions. You can [edit] your question. Thanks.